# ERROR: Task not found: "prefix.css", compress.css" After npm Build:css Command

Tags: css, json, npm, sass, package.json

I am setting up Build process with NPM Scripts and my Issue/question is with the build process, I've followed the instructor's directions perfectly but when I run 'npm build:css'

Error message:

> ERROR: Task not found: "prefix.css", compress.css"
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! natours@1.0.0 build:css: `npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix.css compress.css`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the natours@1.0.0 build:css script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Landing page for Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "concat:css": "concat -o css/style.concat.css css/icon-font.css css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix.css compress.css"
  },
  "author": "D",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.5",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: So why you post an image if the error is already in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've followed the instructor's directions perfectly

Did you?

```
"build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix.css compress.css"
```

should be:

```
"build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix:css compress:css"
```

The error is self explanatory.

Comment: yes, I did 'npm run build:css' but the error still exists.

Comment: I don’t think you understood what I wrote.

Comment: yes, sir, I didn't understand as you said what it should be. It is the same in package.json file. Can you explain to me more clearly?

Comment: In the `package.json` you have `"build:css": "(…) prefix.css compress.css"`. My answer couldn't be more clear.

Comment: Glad to help. Next time read errors carefully. They usually almost always do help. Consider upvoting my answer please. Good night.